# Angular and SVG: how to dynamically load SVG components?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

in the app that I am developing I have a list of commands (GC->circle, GB->box, GE->ellipse, etc). I have to render them in a SVG.

I followed the guide https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader but there's something that I am missing about SVGs.

I prepared a component for each command (it already sounds dumb because the code is the same except for the template):

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-gc]',
  template: '<svg:circle [attr.r]="command.diameter/2" [attr.stroke]="command.borderColor" fill="#000" [attr.stroke-width]="command.borderThickness" />'
})
export class GCComponent implements OnInit, SVGComponent {
  @Input('[command]') command: ZPL2.GraphicShapeBase;
  constructor() { }
}
```

The component on which I load the rendered command looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[draggableSVGItem]',
  template: '<svg:g svg-host/>'
})
export class DraggableSvgItemComponent implements OnInit {      
  x: number = 0;
  y: number = 0;
  command: ZPL2.GraphicShapeBase;

  @Input()
  set draggableSVGItem(graphicCommand: ZPL2.GraphicShapeBase) {
    this.command = graphicCommand;
    this.x = graphicCommand.x;
    this.y = graphicCommand.y;
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the appropriate component for the command
    var componentType = null;
    if (this.command instanceof ZPL2.GC) {
      componentType = GCComponent;
    }
    if (this.command instanceof ZPL2.GB) {
      componentType = GBComponent;
    }
    if (this.command instanceof ZPL2.GE) {
      componentType = GEComponent;
    }

    // Get the component factory
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);

    // Clear the host view
    let viewContainerRef = this.svgHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    // Dynamically create the component and set its command as the current one
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory,);
    (<SVGComponent>componentRef.instance).command = this.command;
  }
}
```

Everything works almost perfectly. 
The problem I have is that the component creation enclose the SVG elements into a DIV and consequently the output is blank:

[image: extra div]

I'm new to Angular, do you have any suggestion to get rid of that DIV and to make the code simpler?

## EDIT

I solved it following the example at this link: https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2017/06/17/angular-dynamically-inserting-svg-into-an-element/

By binding the innerHTML property of the element I can set a different SVG content depending on the command class type:

template: `<svg:g [innerHTML]="svg"/>`

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Get the appropriate component for the command
  var html = ``;
  if (this.command instanceof ZPL2.GC) {
    html = `<circle r="` + this.command.diameter / 2 + `" stroke="` + this.command.borderColor + `" fill="#000" stroke-width="` + this.command.borderThickness + `" />`;
  }
  if (this.command instanceof ...

  this.svg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

In this way I don't need to create a component for each command. Each command can have its own getHTML() method.

The drawback is that I have no binding with the command's properties, right?

Comment: This seems a bit over engineered to what the perceived intention is to begin with. I'm not sure I understand the benefit of this over instead of say just supplying one svg with the 3 [necessary elements](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) as `symbol` in `defs` and toggling what's necessary at the instance?

Comment: I have a file with a list of commands that generate a zebra label (ZPL2). The app I am developing is an editor for this kind of labels. I need to be able to load and create such elements dynamically as I don not know them prior. Elements can be custom graphics, text, barcodes. I am starting with simple shapes.

Comment: @MichelemppMarostica Did you ever come to a solution that you liked?

Comment: @Filippi not with a single SVG, I ended up putting every item in its own div

Answer (score 3):

My Solution for load dynamically svg file (for the same component):

In .html template (I implemented that with drop-down list, but here I cut the code for the example):

```
<object *ngIf="currentSVG" type="image/svg+xml" [data]="SVGFile"></object>
```

In .ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//component and class definition

SVGFile: SafeUrl;
currentSVG: string;

constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { ... }

//your code  

this.currentSVG = True;
this.SVGFile = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('<your SVG file path>');
```

Note: SVG files should be located in assets directory.

Comment: Hi, so you suggest to use a list of `<object *ngIf="[...]"/>` instead of the series of `if (this.command instanceof [...])` ? This can be a clearer solution

Comment: Hi, not exactly. I suggest to load different svg files via drop-down list, so that when the user choose an element from the list,  a click event is triggered and 'this.SVGFile' is updated (with the adapted path that you want).

Comment: I see, I don't have files. My SVGs are generated at runtime in memory.

Comment: Will this allow adding click events to single svg-paths for example? Or no, because the svg will now only be referenced similar to how you can reference whole svgs with the html <img src="assets/example.svg"> element?